# How to import Elementary OS to Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, settings, elementary

I want to switch from Elementary OS to Ubuntu. So how do I import all my programs and files to Elementary OS. And is it the best idea to switch to Ubuntu? Is it any different, except GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent any change inside EOS that could conflict with Ubuntu the best method is to re-install. This basically applies to all changes you want to do between 2 different operating systems unless there is a clear cut way of switching.

Backup your personal data. You could backup some settings by exporting them. Like bookmarks from browsers if you do not use an on-line synch. All other settings I would not bother and just restart from Ubuntu.

But! when you have done that there is nothing stopping you from trying it out. This is the command to install a Ubuntu desktop

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If it works you can pick it at login and see if it works as expected.

And ...

```
sudo apt-get purge elementary-desktop
```

should remove elementary desktop (or pantheon).

> And is it the best idea to switch to Ubuntu?

That is a personal question only you can answer.

> Is it any different, except GUI.

The GUI is the main difference.

Comment: so there's no diffrence? because i have some problems for example: i can't run pycharm, problems with bluetooth settings... so will switching to ubuntu original fix any of this?

Comment: @1234filip There is a big difference.  With Ubuntu you can get support here on Ask Ubuntu!  With Elementary OS, you have to go [there](http://elementary.stackexchange.com)

Comment: but if there's diffrence just in the gui why should i switch. i just say that i have ubuntu 14.04

Comment: The deskop is totally different. And the desktop  is also the key part of the operating system. Show 1 image of EOS and it will be pretty clear it is not Ubuntu. Plus the default apps are different too.